# How to fix "There is no claims identity." error?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-code-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins provides instructions how to get OAuth access to SharePoint.

The process starts with creating a principal on the **AppRegNew.aspx** page and then getting an authorization code from **OAuthAuthorize.aspx** like https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/<site>/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=ca59f604-dbe2-5297-85d6-6358e4d162df&scope=List.Read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%mydomain%2Ecom%2Fredirectaccept.aspx

However, when following the instructions, in step 3 rather than showing the consent page the SharePoint tenant responds with

> #### Sorry, something went wrong
>
> There is no claims identity. Please make sure the web application is configured to use Claims Authentication.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?